# Satellizer and twitter login

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twitter, satellizer

I am using satellizer jjs module for login using facebook and twitter. I am using angular js for front end and node js for backend. I am developing a website. When login using twitter the user is not able to come back to the application window after successful authorization in another window.
Kindly suggest something so that user automatically sent to application window after login.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use implicit oAuth2 flow.
I'd initialize the $auth provider with `responseType:'token'`
Example:

```
$authProvider.twitter({
  url: '/auth/twitter',
  responseType:'token'
});
```